# Why does my thread invoke a function object instead of assigning its return value to my packaged_task’s future object?

Tags: c++, future, stdthread, packaged-task

I want learn how to retrieve the return value of a function using a packaged_task.

In the code below I create a thread that runs my function DoTask. I then bind that function to packaged_task  and get it to wait while I bind it to a packaged_task myTask. I extract myTask’s future object. Now I unblock the condition variable on DoTask (notify_one) to let it run to completion. I do a get() on myTask’s future to retrieve the value of the return bool in DoTask.

But instead of waiting for DoTask to return, DoTask enters code that does an “INVOKE a function object” and get() never gets executed.

What is keeping DoTask from setting the future I expected it to and instead invokes a function object?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <future>
#include <memory>
#include <thread>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>

std::condition_variable notifyCondVar;
std::mutex mu;

bool DoTask() 
{
  {
    std::unique_lock< std::mutex > locker( mu );
    notifyCondVar.wait( locker );
  }
  return true;
}

int main()
{
  std::thread packageTaskThread( DoTask );
  std::packaged_task< bool() > myTask( std::bind( DoTask ) );
  std::future< bool > taskFuture = myTask.get_future();
  notifyCondVar.notify_one();
  bool okay = taskFuture.get();
  packageTaskThread.join();

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a thread running `DoTask`, *and* a packaged_task instructed to run `DoTask`. You never actually executed the task, so the following two things are wrong:

1. The thread will never terminate;
2. The task's future will never be satisfied.

Perhaps you meant to move-construct the thread from the packaged task, instead:

```
#include <future>
#include <memory>
#include <thread>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>

std::condition_variable notifyCondVar;
std::mutex mu;

bool DoTask() 
{
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locker(mu);
  notifyCondVar.wait(locker);

  return true;
}

int main()
{
  std::packaged_task<bool()> myTask([]() { return DoTask(); });
  std::future<bool> taskFuture = myTask.get_future();

  std::thread packageTaskThread(std::move(myTask));

  notifyCondVar.notify_one();
  bool okay = taskFuture.get();

  packageTaskThread.join();
}
```

You can see usage examples for `std::packaged_task` in [this documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/packaged_task).

*(BTW your extra scope block in `DoTask` is entirely redundant.)*

Comment: I see that I didn’t have a clear idea of the three usage patterns – lambda, bind and thread – described in your documentation link. (BTW, DoTask(); needs a return to compile)

Comment: @rtischer8277: Good spot.